# Can I use fscanf to read a character array and an integer seperated with a comma in my file.txt (in C)

Tags: arrays, c, file, gcc, scanf

I don't know much about file handling in C. In my `file.txt` the first row is like this:

```
25031470760,1234
```

I want to read them seperately such as:

```
FILE* filep = fopen("myfile.txt","r");
char id[20];
int password;
fscanf(filep,"%s,%d");
```

I want `id = 25031470760` and `password = 1234`
but when i print them:

`printf("%s %d",id,password);`
the output is ridiculously this : `25031470760,1234 2201625031470760,1234 22016`

**I would be very appreciated to your help.**

Comment: Check your `fscanf` call. It is simply wrong.

Comment: I don't see how your code can produce the output you posted. As Eugene said, your fscanf() function is, well...dysfunctional. Have you listed the actual output of your program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fscanf(filep,"%s,%d");` fails in various ways.

**No width limit**

`"%s"` is subject to overrun.  Use a width limit

```
char id[20];
...
fscanf(filep,"%19s,%d");
```

**Won't stop on `,`**

`"%s"` will read and save `','`.  Consider `" %[^,\n]"` to 1) skip leading white-space and then 2) save all non-comma, non-end-of-line characters.

```
fscanf(filep," %19[^,\n],%d");
```

**Check return value**

```
if (fscanf(filep," %19[^,\n],%d") == 2) {
  Success();
} else {
  Fail();
}
```

**Missing check of `fopen()` success**

```
FILE* filep = fopen("myfile.txt","r");
if (filep == NULL) {
  puts("File to open");
  return fail;  // Illustrative code.
}
```

**Perhaps other issues**

Given OP's 2 outputs, I suspect [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/2410359).

Comment: I used fscanf(filep,"%11s,%d",id,&password); and it worked. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Standby Be sure to check the return value of `fscanf()` before using the data that was read.